# A-FRAME WebXR Could not create a session error

Tags: aframe

Hi I'm developing an 360 video player website with A-FRAME and I got some troubles.
The webpage works well when I control with keyboard and mouse. (When I click VR icon that makes me enter VR mode, it works well. I can control camera view angle with mouse)
Howerer, if I put on my oculus rift s headset and try to enter VR mode, these errors come up.

**"Could not create a session because: Something went wrong initializing the session in the runtime"**

**"Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The specified session configuration is not supported."**

I also tried to enter VR mode in web app from aframe.io such as "Hello WebVR" and "A-Painter" but same situation. I searched the error messages on google, but I never found the solutions for those errors.
I tried these things.

> -updating graphic drivers
>
> -reinstall my oculus program
>
> -checking OpenXR runtime setting in Oculus software Settings

My system is as follows.

> Windows 10 Enterprise 21H2(OS build 19044.1706)
>
> Intel i7-9700
>
> ZOTAC RTX 2080 Ti
>
> Oculus Rift S, Oculus Rift (none of them works...)
>
> Chrome version 101.0.4951.67

If anyone has experienced similar troubles, I really appriciate if you share how you fix them.